# Query parameter values does not bind to Spring Pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-ui, query-string

My spring boot applications controller contains a method as below with optional Pageable parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Override
public Page<MarkupView> getAllMarkup(Pageable pageable) {
    System.out.println("Page size" + pageable.getPageSize() ) // prints 20
    return markupService.getAllMarkups(pageable);
}
```

My problem is when I pass query parameters with swagger-ui those values does not bind to the pageable object. Why I said that is it prints pageSize as 20 whether I pass value 5 as query parameter.

*request URL :* 
*http://localhost:8080/api/markups?offset=2&pageNumber=1&pageSize=5*

above Get request returns me Page object which contains all **MarkupView** records.

Comment: I use page=1&size=5 instead of pageNumber &pageSize

Comment: Your parameters have the wrong name. You should be using `page` and `size` instead. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting

Comment: Thanks all, Its works, But I wonder why does swgger-ui take those parameters like I used above. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By referring to section 5 of [Spring Data Web Support](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-web-support). Please check if you follow the configuration mentioned. Then update the query parameter name from `pageNumber` to `page` and `pageSize` to `size`.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure why you implemented it like that. I would rather take in the request parameters in as is and then set them in a pojo instead of doing this. I tested this on my machine and it would bind as expected. See if the below implementation helps!

```
  @GetMapping("/api/markups")
  @Override
  public Page<MarkupView> getAllMarkup(final @RequestParam(name = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize, final @RequestParam(name = "offset", required = false) Integer offset, final @RequestParam(name = "pageNumber", required = false) Integer pageNumber) {
    System.out.println("Page size" + pageSize ); 
    System.out.println("offset" + offset );
    System.out.println("Page number" + pageNumber );
    return markupService.getAllMarkups(pageSize,offset,pageNumber);
  }
```

Comment: That beats the purpose of using Spring and automatic binding to objects.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes! What I want is to achieve automatic binding to object.

Comment: Ouch! Yup, my bad! So How can this be made better? Also, isn't it an overkill to bind params like page number and size to an object?

Comment: @SachithraWishwamal can you add your DTO to the question

Comment: No, because the `Pageable` is an object understood by Spring Data, which you can use directly in method arguments.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, will read up on that before jumping the gun again.